# How do you construct a C makefile so that it compiles the source.c file?

Tags: c, makefile

I have three files. main.c, graph.c, and graph.h.
I know the code works without a makefile because I tested it on the onlinegbd compiler. Everything runs smoothly.

When I try to run my makefile in terminal, I get an error of:

```
undefined reference to "function"
```

Where "function" is every function I call in main that is in graph.c.

So this leads me to think I'm not compiling graph.c in my makefile.

*edit*
I have confirmed it is the makefile. I compiled it using:

```
gcc -o xGraph main.c graph.c
```

And it ran without issue.
Here is the makefile:

```
CC = gcc

VPATH = SRC INCLUDE

TARGET = XGraph

CFLAGS = -g -Wall

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): main.o graph.o
    $(CC) main.o graph.o -o $(TARGET)

main.o: main.c graph.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.c

graph.o: graph.c graph.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) graph.c

clean:
    rm *.o *~ $(TARGET)
```

Comment: You get that error with what code?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not very well versed with makefiles at all. That one is edited from a three year old c++ makefile I had.

Comment: The recipes for `main.o` and `graph.o` are broken.  Just delete them and let `make` use its default rules.  (This will ignore the graph.h dependency, but worry about that later.)

Comment: It's good you got an answer.  In the future when asking questions like this it's best to include in your question the command you typed and the full output you got; in particular the commands that make generated and the error messages you see as they are generated (not extracted and shown separately).  If there are too many errors which are similar, show just the _FIRST_ 4 or 5 error lines (not the last errors!  The first errors are almost always the more interesting ones).  Cut and paste and format appropriately.  Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When compiling C code the first stage is to generate `.o` files.  Pass the `-c` flag to gcc to do this.

```
main.o: main.c graph.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c

graph.o: graph.c graph.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c graph.c
```

Comment: Thank you for the solve. I was coming up empty.

Comment: But `make` already has implicit rules to compile C source files.  Those two rules are redundant.

Comment: Yes; but, using the implicit rules isn't very educational.  Most simple programs can be compiled entirely with automatic prerequisites and implicit rules.

Answer (score 2):

In C, there are two types of undefined reference errors. The first results in an `implicit declaration of function` error, while the second gives your `undefined reference`. The first says `gcc` cannot find a *definitition* of your function. but the second means `gcc` sees nothing wrong with your code, then tries to link object files using `ld` and *that* crashes the code. Make sure that your source files are included in compilation and they have declarations, not just definitions. Also, providing a minimum reproducible example of your code might be helpful here.

Comment: Okay, I am going to get started on this now. It might take me a few.

Answer (score 1):

Your simplest `Makefile` can be:

```
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

xGraph_objs = main.o graph.o

xGraph: $(xGraph_objs)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(xGraph_objs)

main.o graph.o: graph.h
```

as there are implicit rules (that use the `$CFLAGS` variable, so you don't need to add rules to do the compilation, just to specify the extra dependencies between the objects and the header file)

The structure I use frequently for small projects is very similar to yours:

```
targets = xGraph
toclean = $(targets)

xGraph_deps = # no dependencies to link the executable. (E.g. creating a library needed to link this)
xGraph_objs = main.o graph.o
xGraph_libs = # no libs to specify at link time. (E.g. -lm -lX11)
xGraph_ldfl = # no flags for the linker. (E.g.  -L/usr/local/lib)
toclean += $(xGraph_objs)

all: $(targets)
clean:
    $(RM) $(toclean)

xGraph: $(xGraph_deps) $(xGraph_objs)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(xGraph_ldfl) $(xGraph_objs) -o $@ $(xGraph_libs)
```